# Very slow database query migrating from django 1.8 to django 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-1.8, django-3.2

I migrated a project from django1.8 to django3.2. I'm using the same database but the function I use to build a report is four times slower (8 seconds on Django1.8 and 30/40 seconds with django3.2). The database is MySQL version 5.7 (I also tried version 8.0.32 but nothing changed).

This is the query:

```
qs = PartitaDanno.objects.filter(incarico__cliente_intestatario_fattura_id=8006
    ).select_related('incarico', 'anagrafica_assctp', 'incarico__naturaincarico'
    ).prefetch_related('rate'
    ).order_by('-incarico__anno', '-incarico__numero', 'pk')
```

PartitaDanno is a table with 16000 rows and the model has 215 fields (I know..I didn't write it). The result of this query are just 1700 rows..a very small result.
The unusual thing is that even if I use a simple query on this model like

```
qs = PartitaDanno.objects.filter(incarico__cliente_intestatario_fattura_id=8006)
```

It takes 20 seconds to iterate through result of this basic query..I don't understand.
The raw sql query is the same in both versions of Django. This is the first queryset raw query:

```
SELECT `sinistri_partitadanno`.`id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`created`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`modified`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`incarico_id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipologia_controparte`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`fase`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`competenza_giurisdizionale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`soggetto`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`anagrafica_assctp_id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`luogo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`compagnia_id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`riferimento_compagnia`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipo_di_danno`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipo_lesioni`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipologia_vittima`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`modello_veicolo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`targa_veicolo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`riserva_iniziale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`riserva_parziale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_richiesta_danni_ctp`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`reiezione_cautelativa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_reiezione_cautelativa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`importo_richiesto_da_ctp`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_incarico_nostro_perito`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipologia_perizia`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`nominativo_perito`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_perizia_negativa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`motivazioni_perizia_negativa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_interlocutoria_inviata_dal_perito`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`importo_stimato_dal_perito`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_perizia_dal_nostro_perito`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`riparazione_antieconomica`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_incarico_medico_legale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_perizia_dal_nostro_medico_legale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_invio_offerta_tramite_transazione_quietanza`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_reiezione_indennizzo_risarcimento`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`pagamento_parziale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`capitale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_pagamento_capitale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`anagrafica_patrocinatore_id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipo_patrocinatore`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`cf_piva_patrocinatore`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`numero_rif_patrocinatore`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`spese_legali`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_pagamento_spese_legali`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`integrazione_capitale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_pag_integraz_capitale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`integrazione_spese_legali`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_pag_integraz_spese_legali`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`note_generali`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`note_pagamenti`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`cessione_del_credito`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`veicolo_sostitutivo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`importo_noleggio_veicolo_sostitutivo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`altre_spese_accessorie_richieste`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`importo_altre_spese_accessorie_richieste`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`importo_onorari_richiesti`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`liquidazione_diretta_senza_perizia`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`offerta_lesioni_a_stralcio`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`richiesto_nulla_osta_giudice_tutelare`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_nulla_osta_giudice_tutelare`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`note_fase_precontenziosa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`certificato_di_chiusura_malattia`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_cert_chiusura_malattia`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`richiesta_accesso_agli_atti`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_richiesta_accesso_agli_atti`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_risposta_accesso_agli_atti`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`note_accesso_agli_atti`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`atto_di_citazione`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_notifica_atto_di_citazione`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`valore_causa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`valore_giudiziale_riservato`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`mediazione`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_notifica_mediazione`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_risposta_mediazione`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`note_su_adr`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`domiciliatario_sled_id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`autorita_evocata_id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`nome_del_giudice`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`sezione_tribunale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`ruolo_generale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`prima_udienza_in_atto_introduttivo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`adempimento_udienza`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`rinvio_all_udienza_del`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`scadenza_adempimento`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipologia_adempimento`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`numero_sentenza`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_sentenza`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`pubblicazione_sentenza`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_prima_udienza`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`note`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`adempimento_svolto`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`reclamo_ivass`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_reclamo_ivass`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`studio_legale_incaricato`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`dettaglio_riserva_rivalsa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`dettaglio_esborsi_pagati_sled`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`descrizione_esborsi_pagati_sled`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`dettaglio_importi_recuperati_da_sled`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`ricevuta_richiesta_danni_ctp`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_richiesta_danni_ctp`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`termini_legali_di_risposta_ctp`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`motivi_reiezione_cautelativa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_integraz_elementi_ctp`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_transazione_quietanza_firmata`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_rifiuto_offerta`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`motivi_reiezione_indennizzo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`clausole_particolari`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`incarico_gestione_relitto`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`destinazione_relitto`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_incarico`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`valore_commerciale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`spese_diverse_relitto`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipologia_spesa_relitto`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`importo_vendita`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_bonifico`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`acquirente`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_voltura_demolizione`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`note_gestione_relitti`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_citazione`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_richiesta_pagamento_bo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`stato_chiusura`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipo_chiusura_con_pagamento`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipo_chiusura_senza_seguito`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipo_chiusura_con_recupero`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_apertura`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_chiusura`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_riapertura`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`anagrafica_cessionario_id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`minore`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`anag_esercente_potesta_id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`anagrafica_erede_id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`investigazione_antifrode`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_appuntamento_perito`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_doc_completi`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_incarico_agenzia_pa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_doc_da_agenzia_pa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`veicolo_in_deposito`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`veicolo_sotto_sequestro`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_dissequestro`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_invio_offerta_vendita`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipologia_perizia_medica`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`nominativo_medico`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_appuntamento`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_interlocutoria_medica`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_perizia_medica_negativa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`motivazioni_perizia_medica_negativa`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tassa_di_registro`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_pagamento_tassa_di_registro`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`negoziazione_assistita`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`causa_penale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_prossima_udienza`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`note_causa_penale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`decreto_ingiuntivo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`tipologia_rito`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`fase_procedura`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`conclusione`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`numero_di_polizza`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`conducente`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`anagrafica_conducente_id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`estratti_autentici`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`nome_notaio`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_autentica`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_invio_messa_in_mora`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_ricezione_messa_in_mora`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_notifica_titolo_giudiziale`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`atto_di_precetto`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_notifica_precetto`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`somme_incassate`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_incasso`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`n_decreto_ingiuntivo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`r_g_decreto_ingiuntivo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_emissione_decreto_ingiuntivo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_notifica_decreto_ingiuntivo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`capitale_liquidato_decreto_ingiuntivo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`onorari_liquidati_decreto_ingiuntivo`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_apposizione_formula_esecutiva`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`importo_atto_di_precetto`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_notifica_precetto_rinnovazione`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_notifica_pignoramento_mobiliare`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`rge_pignoramento_mobiliare`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_notifica_pignoramento_presso_terzi`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`iscrizione_ruolo_pignoramento_presso_terzi`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`rge_pignoramento_presso_terzi`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_notifica_pignoramento_immobiliare`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`iscrizione_ruolo_pignoramento_immobiliare`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`rge_pignoramento_immobiliare`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`data_trascrizione_pignoramento_immobiliare`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`anagrafica_amministratore_id`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`progressivo_uci_ctp`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`codice_servizio`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`lotto_affidato`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`importo_affidato`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`capitale_azionato`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`calc_capitale_azionato`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`note_recupero_crediti`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`note_status`, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`note_gestione`, `sinistri_incarico`.`id`, `sinistri_incarico`.`created`, `sinistri_incarico`.`modified`, `sinistri_incarico`.`ufficio_sled`, `sinistri_incarico`.`natura_incarico`, `sinistri_incarico`.`naturaincarico_id`, `sinistri_incarico`.`progetto_id`, `sinistri_incarico`.`status`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_chiusura_incarico`, `sinistri_incarico`.`numero`, `sinistri_incarico`.`anno`, `sinistri_incarico`.`numero_incarico_sled`, `sinistri_incarico`.`avvocato_incaricato_id`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_affidamento_avvocato`, `sinistri_incarico`.`cliente_intestatario_fattura_id`, `sinistri_incarico`.`fronter_cliente`, `sinistri_incarico`.`intermediario_id`, `sinistri_incarico`.`numero_incarico_cliente`, `sinistri_incarico`.`locatario_id`, `sinistri_incarico`.`numero_di_polizza`, `sinistri_incarico`.`codice_evento`, `sinistri_incarico`.`tipologia_sinistro`, `sinistri_incarico`.`riserva_totale`, `sinistri_incarico`.`onorari_ed_anticipazioni_sled`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_fattura_onorari_ed_anticipazioni_sled`, `sinistri_incarico`.`numero_fattura_sled`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_incasso_onorari_ed_anticipazioni_sled`, `sinistri_incarico`.`totale_pagato_come_risarcimento`, `sinistri_incarico`.`totale_onorari_ed_anticipazioni_pagati_a_sled`, `sinistri_incarico`.`totale_importi_recuperati_da_sled`, `sinistri_incarico`.`costo_totale_del_sinistro`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_ricezione_fondi`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_del_sinistro`, `sinistri_incarico`.`ora_del_sinistro`, `sinistri_incarico`.`luogo_del_sinistro`, `sinistri_incarico`.`stato`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_ricezione_incarico_sled`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_apertura_incarico_sled`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_riapertura_incarico_sled`, `sinistri_incarico`.`targa_veicolo_assicurato`, `sinistri_incarico`.`assicurato`, `sinistri_incarico`.`proprietario`, `sinistri_incarico`.`nome_conducente`, `sinistri_incarico`.`cognome_conducente`, `sinistri_incarico`.`modello_veicolo`, `sinistri_incarico`.`blackbox`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_installazione_blackbox`, `sinistri_incarico`.`cai_2f`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_ricezione_cai_2f`, `sinistri_incarico`.`autorita_intervenuta`, `sinistri_incarico`.`verbale_autorita`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_ricezione_verbale_autorita`, `sinistri_incarico`.`testimonianza`, `sinistri_incarico`.`nome_testimone`, `sinistri_incarico`.`testimone_id`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_ricezione_testimonianza`, `sinistri_incarico`.`denuncia_di_sinistro`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_ricezione_denuncia_sx`, `sinistri_incarico`.`franchigia_si_no`, `sinistri_incarico`.`importo_franchigia`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_richiesta_copertura`, `sinistri_incarico`.`esito_copertura`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_inizio_copertura`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_fine_copertura`, `sinistri_incarico`.`note_sulla_copertura`, `sinistri_incarico`.`garanzia`, `sinistri_incarico`.`pagamento_totale_del_sinistro`, `sinistri_incarico`.`sinistro_con_lesioni_personali_gravi_o_gravissime`, `sinistri_incarico`.`sinistro_mortale`, `sinistri_incarico`.`liq_cliente_incaricato`, `sinistri_incarico`.`scoperto`, `sinistri_incarico`.`limite_di_indennizzo`, `sinistri_incarico`.`esclusioni_di_polizza`, `sinistri_incarico`.`note_aggiuntive`, `sinistri_incarico`.`importo_da_recuperare`, `sinistri_incarico`.`calc_importo_da_recuperare`, `sinistri_incarico`.`importo_prescritto`, `sinistri_incarico`.`fermo_tecnico`, `sinistri_incarico`.`tutela_legale`, `sinistri_incarico`.`compagnia_tutela_legale_id`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_effetto_polizza`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_scadenza_polizza`, `sinistri_incarico`.`data_pagamento_premio`, `sinistri_incarico`.`codice_agenzia`, `sinistri_incarico`.`onorari`, `sinistri_incarico`.`pratica_procurata_da_id`, `sinistri_incarico`.`rif_uci`, `sinistri_incarico`.`liquidatore_uci`, `sinistri_incarico`.`rif_consap`, `sinistri_incarico`.`branding`, `sinistri_naturaincarico`.`id`, `sinistri_naturaincarico`.`label`, `sinistri_naturaincarico`.`codice_fatturazione`, `sinistri_naturaincarico`.`tipo_workflow`, T5.`id`, T5.`created`, T5.`modified`, T5.`tipo`, T5.`denominazione_giuridica`, T5.`titolo`, T5.`cognome_ragione_sociale`, T5.`nome`, T5.`rappr_sinistro_in_italia`, T5.`indirizzo`, T5.`citta`, T5.`provincia`, T5.`cap`, T5.`telefono`, T5.`fax`, T5.`cellulare`, T5.`email`, T5.`pec`, T5.`codice_fiscale`, T5.`partita_iva`, T5.`professione`, T5.`luogo_di_nascita`, T5.`data_di_nascita`, T5.`sesso`, T5.`codice_iban`, T5.`note`, T5.`blacklist`, T5.`tempi_pagamento`, T5.`codice_fatturazione`, T5.`naturacosto_id`, T5.`nazione`, T5.`codice_uci`, T5.`importata_da_xml` FROM `sinistri_partitadanno` INNER JOIN `sinistri_incarico` ON (`sinistri_partitadanno`.`incarico_id` = `sinistri_incarico`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `sinistri_naturaincarico` ON (`sinistri_incarico`.`naturaincarico_id` = `sinistri_naturaincarico`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `sinistri_anagrafica` T5 ON (`sinistri_partitadanno`.`anagrafica_assctp_id` = T5.`id`) WHERE `sinistri_incarico`.`cliente_intestatario_fattura_id` = 8006 ORDER BY `sinistri_incarico`.`anno` DESC, `sinistri_incarico`.`numero` DESC, `sinistri_partitadanno`.`id` ASC
```

This is the result of queryset.explain():

```
-> Sort row IDs: sinistri_incarico.anno DESC, sinistri_incarico.numero DESC, sinistri_partitadanno.id  (actual time=163.955..172.010 rows=1761 loops=1)
-> Table scan on <temporary>  (cost=2518.91..2544.83 rows=1874) (actual time=153.040..163.135 rows=1761 loops=1)
    -> Temporary table  (cost=2518.90..2518.90 rows=1874) (actual time=153.007..153.007 rows=1761 loops=1)
        -> Nested loop left join  (cost=2331.46 rows=1874) (actual time=0.247..62.163 rows=1761 loops=1)
            -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=1675.43 rows=1874) (actual time=0.224..52.547 rows=1761 loops=1)
                -> Nested loop left join  (cost=1019.40 rows=1677) (actual time=0.089..17.068 rows=1677 loops=1)
                    -> Index lookup on sinistri_incarico using b842d1d4b6d5fa98d8dc06d2c92e02c5 (cliente_intestatario_fattura_id=8006)  (cost=432.45 rows=1677) (actual time=0.081..15.586 rows=1677 loops=1)
                    -> Single-row index lookup on sinistri_naturaincarico using PRIMARY (id=sinistri_incarico.naturaincarico_id)  (cost=0.25 rows=1) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1677)
                -> Index lookup on sinistri_partitadanno using sinistri_pa_incarico_id_398e55f0a3d8c2c0_fk_sinistri_incarico_id (incarico_id=sinistri_incarico.id)  (cost=0.28 rows=1) (actual time=0.018..0.021 rows=1 loops=1677)
            -> Single-row index lookup on T5 using PRIMARY (id=sinistri_partitadanno.anagrafica_assctp_id)  (cost=0.25 rows=1) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1761)
```

Of course it slow down when I start iterating the queryset with a for loop. I don't use iterator() on the complex query because I'm using prefetch_related.

**--- First Edit ---**

This is the result for raw query in phpmyadmin. It's really fast (3.5 seconds to make the query and build the table with results)

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, is this a mysql problem (query performance degraded) or is this a django/python problem (retrieving data from mysql is fine, but iterating the resultset is slow) or is it both?

Comment: I think it's a django/python problem. It's slow when it starts iterating the resultset I think. How can I check where is the problem more deeply? If I use the raw sql in mysql command-line tool (or in phpmyadmin) it's very fast.

Comment: Testing the raw query is a good indication if the problem is with mysql or with python.

Comment: I edited the question with the result of a raw query. It's pretty fast. So I think it's a python/django problem. Any idea?